# Meteor: Relating Items

Tags: mongodb, database-design, meteor

I'm using Meteor and MongoDB, as suggested by the documentation. Coming from a relational database background, I want to understand strategies for modeling data in NOSQL stores.

The scenario is I have `users`, and each `user` has one `vin`. All pretty standard and possible with one collection. But if I want to find the highest `vin` to display some anonymous information about the most recently purchased car, do I just construct a find like:

`Users.find({}, sort: {vin_number: -1})`

or is there a better way to model it? What if a given user has more than one `vin`? In a relational world, that's a "has many" relationship. But if I embed an array of `vins` in a user document, how could I extract the highest number.

As you can see, I am wrestling with the fundamental shift from modeling things as tables to embedded documents.

Any help is appreciated, and (although I know it's not the SO way) I'd love any pointers to places for a gentle migration from the relational modeling patterns to schema-less ones.

Comment: slightly o/t, but 10gen are currently doing an on-line course aimed at node.js developers. m101js, you might find it useful to bridge your relational/sql onto document based databases. https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101JS/2013_August/about

Answer (score 1):

You could use a transform to get the highest vin from the list of vins:

```
Users.find({}, {sort: {vin_number: -1}, transform: function(doc) {
    doc.vin_number = _.max(doc.vin_number_array);
    return doc;
}})
```

I've never tried this, i'm a bit unsure of whether the transform or the sort comes first. But if you had an array of vin numbers in `vin_number_array` in your document, the `vin_number` would end up as the highest of those using underscore's `max` function.

Answer (score 1):

For array fields you can use instruction `$unwind` at aggregation framework. It create different items from your one and you can easily filtrate it as usual.

[Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/)

For example you have item similar to this one:

```
{_id: 'KJDKDSJKSJDK', type: 'car', manufacturer: 'opel', model: 'vectra', vins: [1234,5678]}
```

unwind will create two new items for this projection:

```
{_id: 'KJDKDSJKSJDK', type: 'car', manufacturer: 'opel', model: 'vectra', vins: 1234}

{_id: 'KJDKDSJKSJDK', type: 'car', manufacturer: 'opel', model: 'vectra', vins: 5678}
```

As you can see array field changed to int.

Comment: Should be noted that the aggregation framework does not work on the client side(yet?)

Comment: On the client side you haven't mongo.

Comment: You have mini-mongo on the client in Meteor, and this won't work there, meaning a server side call is needed.

Comment: Mini-mongo is just name for in-memory storage with similar to mongo api. It is hard to imagine sort or do heavy query to it or storage more then 100 items. It's just cache no more. If you want do heavy query you should proceed it at server side.

Comment: All I'm saying is that it should be noted to the OP who is new to this whole environment that your solution cannot be done client side. Not disagreeing with you, just looking out for the OP.

Comment: So, this seems like a pretty complicated solution compared to having two collections. `User: {_id: 'ADFAJLB', whateverElse: 'SDAFDAS'}` and `Auto: {_id: 'DSFDSAFAS', userId: ''ADFAJLB', vin: 'EUIWOR9843032'}`